# colMeans function in R and running into problems with columns of size 1

Tags: r

I had a question regarding the colMeans function.  Is there a version of this that will not return an error when it runs into a column of length one?  For example

```
temp<-cbind(c(2,2),c(3,4))
colMeans(temp)

[1] 2.0 3.5
```

But for this one

```
temp2<-c(2,2)
colMeans(temp2)

Error in colMeans(temp2) : 
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

But, if I apply the function mean to each column it properly comes up with the value of 2 and 2.

I wrote a function to do this

```
testfun<-function(i,x){
mean(x[,i])
}
sapply(1:ncol(x),testfun,x)
```

which gives the same results as colMeans.
I've heard that colMeans is supposed to be much faster than this method.  So, is there a version of colMeans that will work when my column is of size 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Paul points out, `colMeans` expects "an array of two or more dimensions" for its `x` argument (from `?colMeans`). But `temp2` is not an array

```
is.array(temp2)
# [1] FALSE
```

`temp2` can be made into an array:

```
(tempArray <- array(temp2, dim = c(1, 2)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    2

colMeans(tempArray)
# [1] 2 2
```

Perhaps `temp2` came from subsetting an array, such as

```
array(temp2, dim = c(2, 2))[1, ]
```

But this is not an array. To keep it as an array, add `drop = FALSE` inside the brackets:

```
array(temp2, dim = c(2, 2))[1, , drop = FALSE]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    2
```

Then you can use colMeans on the subsetted array.

Answer (score 4):

The `colMeans` function is meant for n-dimensional arrays. When your column is of size 1 (1 colum, or 1 row??) you effectively have a vector. On a vector, using just `mean` is fine. In terms of speed, calculating the mean of a million numbers is very fast:

```
> system.time(mean(runif(10e5)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.038   0.000   0.038
```

Answer (score 2):

@PaulHiemstra and @BenBarnes provide correct answers.   I just want to add to their explanations.

**Vectors vs. arrays**

Vectors are the fundamental data structure in R.  Almost everything is internally represented as a vector, even lists (with the exception of a special kind of list, the dotted pair list, see `?list`). Arrays are simply vectors with an attribute attached, the `dim` attribute, which describes the object's dimensions. Consider the following:

```
v <- c(1:10)
a <- array(v, dim = c(5, 2))
length(v) # 10
length(a) # 10
attributes(v) # NULL
attributes(a) # $dim 10  1
is.vector(v) # TRUE
is.array(v) # FALSE
is.vector(a) # FALSE
is.array(a) # TRUE
```

Both `v` and `a` are length `10`. The only difference is `a` has the `dim` attribute attached to it. Because of this added attribute, R treats `a` externally as an array instead of a vector. Modifying just the `dim` attribute can change R's external representation of an object from array to vector and back:

```
attr(a, "dim") <- NULL
is.vector(a) # TRUE
is.array(a) # FALSE
attr(v, "dim") <- c(5, 2)
is.vector(v) # FALSE
is.array(v) # TRUE
```

In your example, `temp2` is a vector object, thus lacking a `dim` attribute. `colMeans` is expecting an `array` object with a `dim` attribute of at least length 2 (two dimensional). You can easily convert `temp2` to a two dimensional array with a single column:

```
temp3 <- array(temp2, dim = c(length(temp2), 1)) 
# or:
temp4 <- temp2
attr(temp4, "dim") <- c(length(temp2), 1)
is.array(temp2) # FALSE
is.array(temp3) # TRUE
is.array(temp4) # TRUE
```

**colMeans() vs. mean()**

@PaulHiemstra is right, instead of converting a vector to a single column for `colMeans()`, it is much more common to just use `mean()` on a vector. However, you are correct that `colMeans()` is faster. I believe this is because it does a bit less checking for well-formed data, but we'd have to look at the internal C code to be sure.  Consider this example:

```
# Create vector "v" and array "a"
n <- 10e7
set.seed(123) # Set random number seed to ensure "v" and "a[,1]" are equal
v <- runif(n)
set.seed(123) # Set random number seed to ensure "v" and "a[,1]" are equal
a <- array(runif(n), dim=c(n, 1))

# Test that "v" and "a[,1]" are equal
all.equal(v, a[,1]) # TRUE

# Functions to compare
f1 <- function(x = v){mean(x)} # Using mean on vector
f2 <- function(x = a){mean(x)} # Using mean on array
f3 <- function(x = a){colMeans(x)} # Using colMeans on array

# Compare elapsed time
system.time(f1()) # elapsed time = 0.344
system.time(f2()) # elapsed time = 0.366
system.time(f3()) # elapsed time = 0.166
```

`colMeans()` on the array is faster than `mean()` on either a vector or an array. However, most of the time this speed-up will be negligible. I find that it is more natural to just use `mean()` on a vector or single-column array. But, if you are a true speed demon you might sleep better at night knowing that you are saving several hundred milliseconds of processing time by using `colMeans()` on single column arrays instead.